# gitosis always asks for git password

Tags: windows, git

I've just followed the simple gitosis install instructions on an Ubuntu server, such as these http://blog.agdunn.net/?p=277

On the server I log in as "mark", and into `/home/mark/.ssh/` I copied my keyfiles `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` from my laptop.

I used that `id_rsa.pub` when initialising the gitosis stuff, and can happily connect locally when logged in as 'mark'.

From my laptop though, where I have the same keys, I can't connect.  I just get an error:

```
git clone git@support:gitosis-admin.git
Initialized empty Git repository in u:/gitosis-admin/.git
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The server is Ubuntu 9.04, the client is a Win7 laptop with Cygwin and WinSysGit.

Comment: Is your key in the authorized_keys file of the git account on the server? I'd double-check that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally the `git clone` is going to be doing `ssh git@support`, and Git's "remote end hung up unexpectedly" error message usually means that `ssh` failed to log into the server.  So run that `ssh` command yourself and see what error message you get -- that might enlighten you already.  Or if not, add `-vvv` to get a bunch of debugging output.

(I'm a little confused because your title doesn't match your description -- is there another way you tried that was asking for a password instead of giving the "hung up unexpectedly" error message?)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of git your running you may have to specify the branch you wish to clone. So it clone git@support:gitosis-admin.git master. Where master is the default.